# How to pick up automatically previous month/year's data to use in name manager in Excel

Tags: excel, offset

I am trying to automate an Excel report and I would like to find a formula that finds the latest cell with data in it (`MMM-YY` info in it) and then picks up that month's previous year and previous month's data. So for example, if the last cell worth of data is `Apr-17`, it automatically finds `Mar-17` as the previous month or `Apr-16` as the previous year and I am able to pick that month/year worth of data.

So far, I have managed to put in a formula that picks the latest cell with data and collects that month's data as well as the last 12 months:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A),1,-12,10)
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A),1,1,10)
```

I have created this lookup formula that picks the latest cell/month of data but I'm not sure how it can be combined with the formulas above to get what I need:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A:A))),Sheet1!A:A)
```

[image: Raw data]

[image: offset name manager]

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks and Best Regards, Alexandra

Comment: The question is little confusing. Can you update the screenshots of your excel. Need to see the data physically in sheet 1 too

Comment: Sure. Please see a screenshot where all data is added and another screenshot with the two offset formulas I have managed to do to pick the current month's data as well as the last 12 months' data.

Comment: Actually, can you see my images?

Comment: yes , can you tell me how and where you use the formula. And whats your desired output?

Comment: Great. I would like a formula that looks up Column 1 on Sheet1, finds the latest cell with data (in this case A41) and then sums up data from column B to K for the previous month (in this case A40). I want this automatic so next month when the last cell with data is A42 I get sum(B41:K41) as the previous month. I will use the formula on name manager.

Comment: Above I described the formula  I would like to pick last month's data. The other formula I am after is a formula that looks up Column 1 on Sheet1, finds the latest cell with data (in this case A41) and then sums up data from column B to K for the previous 12 months automatically. In this case I'd have SUM(B30:K41). As soon as A42 contains data, the sum would be SUM(B31:K42)

Comment: perfect got it.. one last question. Where you will sum and display the output. Which column/cell in the sheet?

Comment: mmm not sure about that because it's for a name on the name manager so I will use it in multiple places. I think I might have managed to find the formulas, which are much simpler than where I was getting to with lookups and stuff: OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1),1,1,10) for previous month and 
OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A)-23),1,12,10) for same period previous year

Comment: How would you sum these values then? after using offset?

Comment: I'd use them doing the calculations for example: (sum(name_manager1)-sum(name_manager2))/sum(name_manager2)

Comment: did you check my answer. does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try these formula for summing the values,

Previous month,

`=SUM(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A)-2),1):OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A)-2),10))`

Previous year,

`=SUM(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A)-13),1):OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(COUNT(Sheet1!$A:$A)-2),10))`

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hello Gowtham. Apologies for not having replied prompter, I've been very busy. I did check and for some reason the formulas are not picked up by name manager? Bizarre. Luckily the formulas I shared on the 28th worked, they might not be the prettiest but they do their job. thanks very much

Comment: @alex_cargo Thats great!! Please upvote if you found my answer useful

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work... so it'll be a 'not useful' for me